# Good practice to handle useless response in express js/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

Am using express js on node for my api service ! In which am using sequelize for query handling purposes !

So in some usecase like creating record, or updating record its simply returning "1" or sometimes nothing !

In this case , am just using

```
res.sendStatus(200);

or sometimes

res.send("success");
```

Is there any better way or this is the correct way to handle ? Or should in need .end() in order to end the process ??

which is a good way to handle these kind of useless responses which we dont need to send back ?

Answer (score 1):

This is where `Status 204` comes in to play: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_success

It states: everything is OK (like in 200), but there is simple no need to send a body.

Using express, it's just as simple as: `res.sendStatus(204)`

Answer (score 0):

Usually a json is send back to the client with different information in it that lets the client-side know that the operation that they request through the api is successfull or failed. for e.g. here, you can define a standard json response like this

```
//in case of success of the request
{
   requestStatus: 1,
   ...other data if you want to like new Id of the created data/updated data or info about it if you want or depending upon use case
}
```

or

```
// in case of failure of the request
{
   requestStatus: 0,
   ...other data if you want to like reason for failure, error message or depending upon your use case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line of code, should be fine:

```
//For all bad endpoints
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Not a good endpoint, why are you here? Go play FIFA.'})
})
```

If you want you can generate an error HTML file, but since it's back-end, JSON format is strongly suggested. You can also add `success: false` for more clarity.